# Learning to test Vue.js projects: product display list

Tags: javascript, testing, vue.js, tdd, karma-mocha

I have a small Vue.js application which fetches and displays a list of products. The application must allow to sort products by size, by price range, alphabetically, etc - all forwards and backwards.

There's unit tests, integration tests, E2E tests etc.

For this particular application, I imagine that:

- Unit Tests are responsible for testing Component methods
- Integration tests: Responsible for the output of a certain action/function:

  - Are there in fact products displayed?
  - Is the price range between 0% and 100% returning any products products?
- E2E tests - not exactly sure.

**In this particular simplistic example, which tests should be there to cover the absolute minimum?**

Any thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your definitions are not exactly correct. I strongly recommand that you take a look at [**Vitali Zaidman**'s *Overview of JavaScript Testing in 2018*](https://medium.com/welldone-software/an-overview-of-javascript-testing-in-2018-f68950900bc3).

You will find the difference between the test types :

> - Unit Tests- Testing of individual functions or classes by supplying input and making sure the output is as expected.
> - Integration Tests- Testing processes or components to behave as expected, including the side effects.
> - UI Tests- (A.K.A Functional Tests) Testing scenarios on the product itself, by controlling the browser or the website, regardless of the internal structure to ensure expected behavior.

You will also learn about all the different **test tools types**, the available frameworks, and basically everything you need to get started and test your components.

Regarding *which tests should be there to cover the absolute minimum*, it's subjective. I personally like to tests every computed properties, watchers, lifecycle hooks and methods (everything that has logic in it), but it can be a bit much in your case, it's your call !

---

Edit :

You asked my *how to write GOOD tests* and, again, it's very subjective.

You can find a new way of doing things for every blog article.

What's most important is that every unit test must assert **only one behavior**. The **tests structure** is also very important

Here's an example, if I had to test a component that display products like in your case :

*Note : Here I am using [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) and [Vue Test Utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/en/) but you can use the framework you like, I am just showing you my way of doing it on very simple and straightforward parts.*

My component has a computed property **displayedProducts**, that takes the **products** data and sort it by name in ascending or descending order, based on a **order** data.

```
// Products.spec.js

// Importing vue-test-utils methods (see the API doc : https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/en/api/)
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
// Importing the tested component
import Products from '@/[...]/Product';

describe('Products.vue', () => {
  // vue-test-utils' wrapper and Vue instance, used in every tests
  let wrapper;
  let vm;
  const productsMock = [{
    name: 'First product',
  }, {
    name: 'Second product',
  }];

  // Before each test, we mount a new instance
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Mounting and inject the products (see the complete documentation here : https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/en/api/mount.html)
    wrapper = mount(Products, {
      products: productsMock,
    });
    vm = wrapper.vm; 
  });

  // Nested 'describe' to make your tests more verbose
  describe('products', () => {
    // Basic test, display the list ordered by names in ascending order
    it('should display the products', () => {
      expect(vm.displayedProducts).toBe(productsMock);
    });

    // Test that the list is reversed when 
    it('should reverse the products list when ordering in descending order', () => {
      vm.order = 'desc';
      expect(vm.displayedProducts).toBe(productsMock.reverse());
    });

    // [...] test that the order's default value is 'asc'
    // [...] test that the list is sorted by the right value, etc...
  });
});
```

Note that the tests are readable, going from the first `describe` to the `it` (example : `Products.vue => products => should display the products`).

You really should read the entire [Vue Test Utils documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/en/), to be familiar with every aspect of Vue.js' tests.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Can you tell me a bit about your philosophy of writing tests? For every integration test I can think of a dozen obvious tests which will near always fail... what is the method behind the madness? In other words, how to write GOOD tests?

Comment: I'm updating my answer to add this part.

Comment: I've add an update with an example and some more informations.